# PhpStorm plugin that generates OpenAPI (Swagger) annotations for Laravel

Tags: laravel, plugins, swagger, phpstorm, openapi

I want to document an existing Laravel 5.8 project, and I want a PhpStorm plugin that will generate some of the annotations automatically from my code.

Is there such a plugin?

Comment: Did you find something for this?

Comment: no, sorry. (and sorry for the late reply)